# Struct pointer cast as uint8_t * throws an error

Tags: c, memory-management, casting, compiler-errors, truncate

in my function I allocate memory for and fill a structure called messagePacket

```
struct messagePacket *packet = malloc(sizeof(struct messagePacket));
//fill
```

When I try to cast the pointer as a (uint8_t *), gcc throws a warning that says: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type

```
sendBuf(..., (uint8_t *)packet);
```

I've been able to do the following just fine, and I understand I can use this approach as a workaround. I'm here because I would rather learn from this than work around it.

```
uint8_t *buf = malloc(sizeof(struct messagePacket));
```

The size of struct messagePacket = 1209 B. My best guess is that the chunk of memory is super large that I gets stored in a high memory address, such as a 16 bye address? But that doesn't fit with the fact that I can malloc a uint8_t * of the same size.

Comment: What does `sendBuf` do ?

Comment: @cnicutar i don't think that matters, because the cast seems to be the problem

Comment: @pivotnig I think it *does* matter because that cast might be superfluous or just plain wrong. As per the standard it already is pretty wrong.

Comment: sendBuf takes in the uint8_t *, creates a similar uint8_t *recvBuf = sizeof(struct messagePacket), send()'s data across a port, select()'s, and recv()'s data

Comment: `code #include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct messagePacket {
int a;
int b[2000];
};
void sendBuf(char * d)
{
int c;
c=*d;
}

int main()
{
struct messagePacket *packet = malloc(sizeof(struct messagePacket));
sendBuf((unsigned char*)packet);
return 0;
}`
I can't see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the warning is about some other argument. Please provide the full code for that line, the prototype for the `sendBuf()` function, and the full compiler warning for the line in question.

As a general idea, the `sendBuf()` function should probably use a `const void *` rather than a `const uint8_t *` for the data to send. See `send()` and friends.

Comment: unwind wins. i need to get better at asking question (ie: at least posting full code). i was passing sizeof(struct messagePacket) to an argument of type uint8_t which is far out of range. i overlooked that because my arguments were on different lines, and the compiler pointed me to the line that i originally asked about

Answer (score 2):

I guess the compiler notices that your struct is larger than 8bit and using `uint8_t` you will only address the first byte of the structure.
Since this seems to be intended you could cast to `(void *)` and then to `(uint8_t *)`.
But you should tell sendBuf the buffer size which is `sizeof(struct messagePacket)`.

Comment: the compiler was too smart for such double casting shenanigans. and send buf definitely gets that size